How can I print the two integers and result on the same line
This is the code I’ve wrote as I’m doing the 100 day course.
 number = input(“write a two digit number\n”)
a = number[0]
b = number[1]
result = int(a) + int(b)
print(result)

I am trying to get the end script to say the sum and the result instead of just displaying the result.
I.e if the two digit number is 32 I want to display: 3 + 2 = 5.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried lots of things but I am extremely new to this and cannot figure it out.

number = input("write a two digit number \n")
a = number[0]
b = number[1]
result = int(a) + int(b)
print(f"{a} + {b} = {result}")

You need to add the variables to the print function. This method uses f-strings, which I don't think you probably wouldn't have come across just yet.
Another simpler way of doing this:
number = input("write a two digit number \n")
a = number[0]
b = number[1]
result = int(a) + int(b)
print(a + " + " + b + " = " + str(result))

You can concatenate strings in the print() function, but you can't concatenate two different data types, thus turning result into str().
Hope this helps.
